# "local area connection doesn't have a valid ip configuration"

Tags: networking, router, windows-10

Alright, I've been running into this error for a while now on this pc's ethernet port, and I've looked around for help. However, my situation seems unique in the sense that I can resolve the issue by disconnecting the power to my pc, waiting for around half an hour, and turning it back on. The down side is that anytime I turn it on or off without this period of time to fully reset, I get the error again. So I am using it to write this and am not currently experiencing any issues, but if I restart my pc, say to try a solution, it will give me the error. This makes troubleshooting particularly annoying because while looking for solutions online, I don't have the issue and can't diagnose it. Then when I am having issues, I have to wait with the power disconnected.

The ethernet and wifi connections to other devices work fine. My network adapter drivers are "up to date." I have tried some troubleshooting through the adapter's settings, but to no avail. A few command prompt responses can be found below. This is technically a matter of convenience, but it is an extremely annoying one. I'm not sure what information you would like to have for this, so I'll attempt to provide anything requested. I'm living in a condo temporarily and the default service provider is Cableone, which I'm not a fan of, but I'm moving in a few months. I have an Asus Z87-Plus mobo with Win 10 and an Asus RT-AC68U router. I'm pretty lost at this point.

Adapter Properties: I have gone back and forth with the ipv4 settings (automatic vs specific ip) and have toggled the ipv6 on and off, but it hasn't helped so far. Currently, all ipv4 settings are on automatic and ipv6 is disabled. I'm fairly certain Cableone does not use ipv6

This has been happening on and off for the last few months, but consistently for the last two weeks.

I ran the command submitted as an answer and it currently has no internet capabilities. I ran "ipconfig/all" and will update the information with my phone. Sorry.

```
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name: Owner-pc
Primary Dns Suffix:
Node Type: Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled: No
WINS Proxy Enabled: No
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection specific DNS Suffix:
Description: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V 
Physical Address: E0-3F-49-E8-9A-6B
DHCP Enabled: Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled: Yes
IPv4 Address 169.254.104.16(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway:
NetBIOS over Tcpip: Enabled
```

More info: Dr.Zoo helped me go through some things and I went through a few things on my own. Everything we did has now been undone, but these were some strange occurrences. I got Internet back three times through three different ways, restarting the computer resulted in a connection loss again, and repeating the actions did not reestablish a connection. The first thing that got my Internet back briefly was entering a static IP with a default gateway. The second brief period of Internet was when I unplugged my pc for 30 seconds and plugged it back in. The third time I got the Internet was after I enabled manual assigned IPs on the DHCP settings, created a manually assigned IP with my pc's MAC address and IP, changed my pc to a static IP with the IP used in the DHCP setting, then switched my pc setting back to automatically obtaining an IP. Somehow this enabled DHCP, kept my static IP, and connected me to the Internet until I restarted my pc.

Also of note: The automatically obtained IPs that my pc obtains are not within the DHCP pool range set in the router. I presume that is why when it somehow enabled DHCP, but kept my static IP, it connected.

The ping command came back with 0% loss, <1ms for each ping for an average of 0ms.

Comment: Is your PC set to obtain an IP address automatically? Usually with an IP conflict you get an error about a duplicate IP address on the network, so that may not be the problem. I'm wondering if there is some sort of conflict going on with IPv4 and IPv6. How long has this been occurring?

Comment: @DrZoo I edited the original post to include more information.

Comment: Have you looked at your routers DHCP configuration and tried to assign an IP that is outside of the DHCP pool range?

Comment: @DrZoo I have not. I think I could though. I don't really know what that would do, but I'm open to trying it. By "assign an IP that is outside of the DHCP pool range," do you mean assign an IP for my PC or my Router?

Comment: Assign your PC an address outside of the DHCP range. By assigning your PC an IP address out of the DHCP pool range, it would ensure that there are not two devices on your network receiving the same IP address(unless you know of a device that has a static IP). If you assign your PC a static IP outside of the pool range, and still get that invalid IP message, that would eliminate the problem of a possible duplicate IP address.

Comment: @DrZoo I created a static IP outside of the DHCP pool range and the connection registers as unidentified. I had windows diagnose the issue and it says the problem is: DHCP is not enabled for "Local Area Connection" It has an option to try to repair it as an administrator, but I haven't let it try to fix it yet.

Comment: Go to the command prompt and run `ipconfig /all`, then just copy and paste the results into your answer.

Comment: @DrZoo I updated the original post with the information you asked for. As a side note, I just read the notice, "Please avoid extended discussions in comments..." I'm not sure if that's a concern, but I will continue to follow your lead, as I am new here.

Comment: Can you do a `ping 127.0.0.1` and post the results?

Comment: @DallenRex **Why is your default gateway filed empty ? Enter a correct default gateway and it should be done.**

Comment: What exact problems are you facing? Timeouts, random disconnects?

Answer (score 0):

Try this first. In a cmd prompt with admin privileges run

`netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log`

This will reset everything back to normal. If your router is serving DHCP up then this will put you back on the internet.

I agree with @The_IT_Guy_You_Dont_Like , you have to have a default gateway. I also disagree with every one else in telling you to mess with the DHCP settings. You could be making matters worse and it's not the problem on all pc's getting DHCP from the router would most likely be having problems. Give that command above a shot and let us know how it works.

EDIT

At this point in time I recommend you reset your router using the gui or the hard reset button. I also recommend you run the above command to reset your networking, a second way to do that is just to right click your NIC and select disable, and then renable it.

Comment: ynnekkram and Levi I posted the results of your commands in the initial post. The_IT_Guy_You_Dont_Like I can enter a static IP with a default gateway, but that only worked the first time and hasn't since. When I use the DHCP and automatically obtain my IP from that, it gives me no default gateway. Rowan Kaag Basically, my pc says that the IP configuration is invalid every time the network adapter boots up unless it's from a completely un-powered state like when I unplug my pc and wait. If I do that, it will connect.

Comment: @DallenRex you didn't run my command... please run it and that should fix it up. You need to undue all the commands you entered into your router.

Comment: What is the ipaddress the router is giving you? I will give you the gateway to use.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "giving" me. My router's IP is 192.168.1.109 currently and the IP obtained by my pc is in the command response I edited into my original post.

Comment: The address 169.254.104.16 normally means your computer could not reach an DHCP server. Did you reset it and get that address again? Your router has a weird IP address for a home router, did you set it to .109? and what do you mean by currently? Does it change?

Comment: Oh, @Levi I wrote that all wrong. I meant to explain that I did run your command and restarted th pc as it prompted me to do. I still didn't have a connection after that and I ran the ipconfig/all command to show what it defaulted to. Also, I did go back and revert all the changes I made on my router settings. Sorry about that, totally spaced the whole explaining  part.

Comment: @DallenRex Thats cool, okay so you need to find what your router's IP is. It shouldn't be .109 but maybe for some reason it is. I recommend you reset your router but even if you dont/cant. The gateway will be your routers IP address always, and your DNS should be your routers IP address or 8.8.8.8 to use google DNS in case your routers IP address doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that address was the one I got after I reset. As for the router's address, I did change it. However I was experiencing these issues on my old router, this one on its default IP, and the changed IP. I assumed it hadn't had an effect on the issue. I could change it back though. I'll go reset it. I'll let you know what comes of it.

Comment: No the ip of your router shouldn't have an effect, but its your DHCP range is .50-.200 then your router might accidentally give out it's own IP. I don't really see this happening.... but you never know. If you reset your router you wont have any problems.

Comment: If your not going to reset your router you need to set a private IP of 192.168.1.82      mask of 255.255.255.0    and a gateway of    192.168.1.109   and a DNS of 8.8.8.8      after that you should be able to browse the web. I made 82 up, you could use anynumber betwen 2-250 but not .109 .1 or .255

Comment: I reset my router and went ahead and entered your command again to reset the pc's settings again. I had to setup the WiFi and the password for the WiFi when I logged in to see my router settings from my phone because my pc won't connect enough to even change my router settings. I had an unidentified network with the issue being my pc is missing one or more network protocols. My pc ipv4 settings are all on automatic and the router's IP is 192.168.1.1 with the DHCP enabled and nothing listed under default gateway still.

Comment: A screen shot of the one or more missing network protocols would really help. Now that you have reset your PC TCP/IP stack, and have reset the router, are you getting a address from the Wifi router? Please run Ipconfig again and paste it.

Comment: Your router doesn't have a gateway or your PC? If your pc doesn't have a gateway you can right click your NIC and select Diagnose and see what windows has to say about it... or you can enter a static address of 192.168.1.22 mask of 255.255.255.0 gateway of 192.168.1.1 and DNS of 8.8.8.8 and then a second dns of 192.168.1.1

Comment: The ipconfig results are identical to the ones in the original post. I don't have a good way to take screenshots right now. I'm doing all the communicating with my phone. The missing protocol is "Windows Sockets registry entries required for network connectivity are missing." It also provides an option to restore network protocols to default settings as an administrator. My router's IP is 192.168.1.1 Under the DHCP settings on my router, the default gateway is blank.

Comment: According to this fix for your error you could have a corrupted registry. Messing up the fix could brick your computer so if you do follow the fix you need to do it exactly how it says. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/windows-socket-registry-entries-missing-according/5f54e033-9d49-4de0-bf23-576653641b20?auth=1

Comment: Only other option is to reinstall windows.

Comment: Well, reinstalling windows sounds like a pain, but so does bricking my pc. I'll take a look at that fix and decide if I want to attempt it.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the "Answer" on that page. Given that this is all over my head, the windows socket reset command mentioned in the "most helpful reply" is alluring. Would that be worth a try, as it seems much simpler, or would you recommend just following the "answer's" instructions? Also, since I'm sitting here staring at it, should I let windows "try these repairs as an administrator," or should I avoid that?

Comment: If windows has an option to try repairs I would try that, but I wouldn't get hopeful. I would try them both if the first one you try doesnt work =).